# php memory overflow multi curl

Tags: php, multithreading, performance, memory, curl

I have a PHP routine that I call shell_exec to traverse my own website and build an index.

However since I do this multi-threaded I have been running into problems with memory storage...server memory spikes to 250MB then back down to 100MB randomly.

I am constantly accessing the mysql database during this time; and the php slows down.

Is this possible using php or should I use jsp/java.

Comment: You are not telling us what exactly you are doing in the shell_exec call, so this is impossible to answer really. What tool are you using to do this? Is the memory usage giving you problems?

Comment: I use the rolling_curl library and my code is php-cli /home/ex.php shell_exec I pull via curl_multi and get the collection of data then parse it in my callback function to get the next set of urls to pull via php curl multi - I can't use a cronjob to do this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses a [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) for memory management.  As long as there is a variable declared (could be an array or global) that can be used to access that variable then it is never freed.

The solution is to call `unset()` on anything that has already been used.  To make it use much less memory the parts of the index that have been created should be stored in a sql database. This allows much more data can be unset.

In short this can be done in PHP or JSP and use much less memory by using a database.